# WithEvents Usage

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a few classes that have Public Events. On some forms, these events currently aren't needed nor do I have subroutines defined in the form modules to execute anything if the event is raised.  Yet, when I originally declared the classes I declared them with WithEvents thinking that at some point I would need them.

So I was wondering, for my own education, does declaring classes with WithEvents decrease performance? Would leaving them like this be considered a bad programming technique?

All I found when searching was how to use Events, I never really found anything saying when not to use them.

Comment: `Does declaring classes with WithEvents decrease performance?`, ***no***. `Would leaving them like this be considered a bad programming technique`, ***no***, you may need to have events raised at some point...

Comment: Please consider removing the `c++` tag.